# How to add control in the special column/row of DataList?

Tags: asp.net, datalist

I have a datalist with 3 columns and 3 rows, binding this to a datasource.

```
 <asp:DataList ID="DataList1"  RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <a href="#" class="tile group0 " style="margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px; width: 145px; height: 126px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0%  rgb(102, 128, 0); display: inline;">
       <h5 class="white"><%# Eval("Name") %></h5>
     </a>
   </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:DataList>
```

I have 8 records in datasource.

```
DataTable dt = clsCategoryFactory.GetAllDT();
DataList1.DataSource=dt;
DataList1.DataBind();
```

I want add a button to this , on the column3 rows3.

It is possible to add a control in the special column/row of datalist?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you put your button in footer template.

```
<FooterTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" Text="CheckOut" 
         onclick="btnNext_Click" />
</FooterTemplate>
```

Comment: Because i want to add button to column 3 and row 3 of datalist.